# Logically comma separating address field to form a String

Tags: apex, code, string, address, if

I am trying to create a string of address in this format: `Street, City, State, Country, Zip.` Assume that there is an Address object called addr which has account's shipping address.

```
Address addr = Account__r.ShippingAddress; // Ignore the syntax here and assume that addr has Address.
```

My Challenge here is I want to build a string of the addr with comma separated. Example if shipping address has

```
Shipping Street : 123th Street
Shipping City   : SFO
Shipping State/Province : CA
Shipping Zip/Postal Code: 12345
Shipping Country: USA
```

I want to form a string like `String s = 123th Street, SFO, CA, 12345, USA`

**The catch :**

There could be different possiblity that street may not be present or country may not be present in that case the String should logically display the
commas example - `city, state, zip -> SFO, CA, 12345`. `Also I do not want to display NULL in case street/country/state/zip is not available`. So it is possible that any of the data might be missing and my string should accommodate for missing data and produce the correct comma separated string.

This is what I got started with but I see the logic is getting complex:

```
String street; String city; String state; String country; String zip;
         Address addr = Account__r.ShippingAddress; 
          street = addr.getStreet() <> NULL ? addr.getStreet() : ''; // to make sure I do not display NULL in string
          if(street == NULL){
          city = addr.getCity() <> NULL ? addr.getCity() : '';
          }else{
          city = addr.getCity() <> NULL ? ', ' + addr.getCity() : '';
          }
          if(city == NULL){
          state = addr.getState() <> NULL ? addr.getState() : '';
          }else{
          state = addr.getState() <> NULL ? ', ' + addr.getState() : '';
          }
          if(state == NULL){
          country = addr.getCountry() <> NULL ? addr.getCountry() : '';
          }else{
          country = addr.getCountry() <> NULL ? ', ' + addr.getCountry() : '';
          }
          if(country == NULL){
          zip = addr.getPostalCode() <> NULL ? addr.getPostalCode() : '';
          }else{
          zip = addr.getPostalCode() <> NULL ? ', ' + addr.getPostalCode() : '';
          }
     String addString = street + '' + city + '' + state + '' + country + '' + zip;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For things like this, I use an array:

```
String[] addr = new String[] {
  record.Street, record.City, record.State, record.PostalCode, record.Country
};

for(Integer i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(addr[i] == null) {
    addr.remove(i);
  }
}

String theAddr = String.join(addr, ',');
```

Comment: SF needs a List method to remove nulls.

Comment: @Eric yeah, or a list indexof method would help.

Comment: Maybe make it `for(Integer i = addr.size()-1; i>=0;i--)` to make it easier to add or remove items from the List or more reusable and passing in a list to a utility method

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: This is the current behavior, but not a guaranteed result

Not sure if this is an *anomaly* or not as the sets are unordered but doing this seems to put it back in the order they were added. Also removes a loop.

```
//Build the set of values
Set<String> tmp = New Set<String>{'C','B',null,'A',null,'Z','D'};
System.debug(tmp);
```

> 19:19:42.23 (23673744)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|{null, A, B, C, D, Z}

Notice how they are not in the order they were put in

```
//remove the null values
tmp.remove(null);
```

Now we join the remaining values back

```
System.debug(string.join(New List<String>(tmp),','));
```

> 19:19:42.23 (23854080)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|C,B,A,Z,D

Whala - They are back in the order they were initially added and the nulls are removed

So in your case

```
Set<String> tmp = New Set<String>{
   record.Street, record.City, record.State, record.PostalCode, record.Country
};
tmp.remove(null);
String theAddr = string.join(New List<String>(tmp),',');
```

Comment: This is the current behavior, but not a guaranteed result. We unfortunately cannot rely on this behavior.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Thanks. Wonder if it is do to a pointer to the original list or what....

Comment: @Eric Interesting to see that how behavior changes with NULL.

Comment: @SfdcBat - Not sure I understand. I already have null in there. Without null it works the same

Comment: @Eric Your solution is correct. I was referring to the initially part where you experimented the order with NULL

Answer (score 1):

It will be like this:

```
List<String> lstStr = new List<String>();
Address addr = Account__r.ShippingAddress; 
if(addr.getStreet() !=null) lstStr.add(addr.getStreet());
if(addr.getCity() !=null) lstStr.add(addr.getCity());
if(addr.getState() !=null) lstStr.add(addr.getState());
if(addr.getCountry() !=null) lstStr.add(addr.getCountry());
if(addr.getPostalCode() !=null) lstStr.add(addr.getPostalCode());

String finalAddress = String.join(lstStr,',');
```

Comment: @SfdcBat please don't pick up bad programming habits. The body of an if statement should always be a proper block with { and }. This is perfectly fine logic, but writing compact code like this isn't recommended. It's too easy to make mistakes.

Comment: @sfdcfox thank you for the comment. I did feel that I could make a mistake with the curly braces missing. I have actually used what Eric had given as solution as it had just 4 lines of code

Comment: @SfdcBat - sfdcfox's method is the one guaranteed to work. This answer while it works requires multiple line updates to add or remove values. In addition to the above comments. Also, a reusable utility method would be more useful than code for a specific scenario